# how to design this UI

Tags: android, user-interface

I am trying to design a UI as like in an iPhone app. The image of the design is as follows
[image]

In the above image all the white boxes are of a list view. In those list view i am placing an image View and two set of text view. I have placed a overall custom list view and in that custom list view using relative layout i have place the image view and two text view.

now i want to draw a line between the two text view and when i click on the second text view i am moving to a new activity. At that time i want to show that only the second text view is been clicked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a RelativeLayout:

- The image android:layout_alignParenLeftt="true"
- the first two textViews android:layout_toRightOf="@id/myimage",
- the other textviews below the previous ones (e.g. android:layout_below="@id/author" and with a layout_width="fill_parent"

Check Romain Guy's blog post for a tutorial on a similar (simpler) setup: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html

Answer (score 3):

Check this http://www.androidsnippets.com/clickable-listview-items

> The ClickableListAdapter bases on the
>   API-Demo-Example "Efficient List
>   Adapter". It was refactored to provide
>   a better reusability. Additionally,
>   you can connect OnClickListener and/or
>   OnLongClickListener to each View of
>   your list item. This allows you to
>   create complex interactive lists, or
>   simply using a customized checkbox
>   version.

I had implemented this in a project minus the image view. Heres a [screenshot](http://primal.pw/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/10.png).