# Where can i store default Image on internal storage in android

Tags: android, image, sqlite, storage, internal

For example if i create app like travel guide and i would like to show the attraction place as a list

i'm new to Android. I would like to create a ListView which provide image and some data in each listitem. And after, i touch one of listitem, it will show full information both image and data. The problem now are:

-where can i store image data? in Drawable? or etc. In case, there were a lot of place and i would like to update place more after that.

-Do i need to use SQLite for place's information?

-How should i deal with place's data such as Title, Address, Description? should i store it in XML resource?

-How do i combine both place's data and place image into a listView

Thanks so much for you kindness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where can i store image data? in
>   Drawable? or etc. In case, there were
>   a lot of place and i would like to
>   update place more after that.

You can store the images related to the app in drawables(logo, icons etc). If the app have too many images or would have too many images in future you should consider building a web service and download them when necessary(for example while being searched). You wouldn't want your application to be heavyweight.

> Do i need to use SQLite for place's
>   information?

I would suggest you should. Thus it gives an easy way to structure the data and also helps to buffer it for offline use.

> How should i deal with place's data
>   such as Title, Address, Description?
>   should i store it in XML resource?

Look at the answers to earlier 2 questions.

> How do i combine both place's data and
>   place image into a listView

[how to design this UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945627/how-to-design-this-ui/5945672#5945672)

Comment: Thannks so much i wast my time 3 day for these. Thanks you.

Comment: You could consider ticking the checkbox near the answer if it helped. :-)

Comment: LOL, sorry i'm quite new to everything. Including, programing and this website. anyway thank so much for your help. i will try my best.

Comment: As i told u that i new to programming. About using SQLite, i don't know where should i start. How do i design database? should i create SQLite directly? Should i use Contentprovider? because my application only provide the attraction place in list form and when user click each item, it will show full information. that's it. Do you have any Example? I have studied some of Earthquake project from Profesional Android 2, however i'm still confuse. THanks for your help.

Comment: For SQLite tutorials you can look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298898/android-with-sqlite

Comment: Now i already create Table. My app need only provide data to user. So, i have to insert data by my self in SQLite but i don't know how to add it to my database. For example path : /data/data/com.android.myApp/databases/datastorage.db

and i also use Terminal but i don't know how to open my exiting database for insert new data.

Comment: Look at this tut http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html

Comment: Thank you for your help.. anyway, now i struck in some problem about database coz i know  databases are stored under /data/data/package_name/databases With the emulator i can see all these files (databases) under the proposed directories but moving the application on a real device and installing a file system browser i cannot see any file under /data. i thinks it's because there are some security constrain in (not-rooted) device. so, how do i do. If SQLite not work .. are there any solution for this problem? THanks you